# Where does the bible reference a pagan sun god that was worshipped by the pagan cultures surrounding Israel?

Tags: reference-request, idolatry, pagan, sun

Where is a pagan sun god referenced in terms of the sun that was created by God?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question.  Where did you hear that there was such a statement in the Bible?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two references to pagan sun gods in the old testement. One is to Adrammelech (2 Kin 17:31) and another is to Amon (Jer 46:25).

Adrammelech is never specfically stated in the book of kings, but it is known that the Sepharvaim people of Assyria did worship Adrammelech, their sun God, and the Sepharviam people's worship is directly referenced in the verse. The verse is in regards to foreigners of the Assyria being brought to Israel. Amon is directly referenced in Jer 46:35 ("... I will punish Amon of Thebes and Egypt..."). This is brought up in regards to Jeremiah prophetic verses that were concerning anything against egypt. In a practical discussion of scripture, I would reference Jer 46:25 as a verse where a pagan sun god is referenced, but in more academic circles both can be used.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. This is helpful, but one way to improve your answer would be to provide sources for your analysis of Adrammelech and Amon as sun gods.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: I happened to be reading comments relating to how in some religions l a person is laid to rest facing east and this way that would be facing Christ when HE returns and some in different directions.  And there was a comment someone made, why would you  want to rise to a pagan sun anyway.